# How to get a Grid.Column value in a binding expression

Tags: wpf, binding, datatrigger, wpf-grid

I need set background property by Grid.Column value. My idea was simple DataTrigger like this

```xml
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Grid.Column, ElementName=MyElement}" Value="2">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#F2F2F2"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

MyElement is a generice wpf control for example this:

```xml
<Border x:Name="MyElement" Grid.Column="2">
      Content
</Border>
```

But this is not working and Visual Studio says: `Cann't resolve property Grid`

I can use C# `Grid.GetColumn(MyElement)` as workaround. But I'm wondering, is there any xaml only solution here?

Comment: What is you element 'MyElement'?

Comment: It's generic wpf element. In this case it's 

```
<Border x:Name="MyElement" Grid.Column="2">
      Content
</Border>
```

Comment: @Aakanksha I updated the question. Thank you for helping me

Comment: You cant use a border element to bind Grid.Column property to your textbox. Border will not contain Grid property in the class. Just use the Grid name for binding to the textbox.

Comment: I don't understand. I don't need bind `Grid.Column`I need read `Grid.Column` of some element in `DataTrigger`

Comment: Sorry i misread your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To bind to an attached property, place parentheses around the attached property.

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=(Grid.Column), ElementName=MyElement}" Value="2">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#F2F2F2"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

Comment: Oh that is realy simple. Thank you :-)